# Quote formatting with Ctrl+Q puts the > in annoying places

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, blockquote

If I paste in a quote and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> it will apply quote formatting like so:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

But the markdown looks like this:

```
> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

The editor has added in linebreaks where the line would have to cut, when in reality all it needs is this:

```
> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

And it auto wraps:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Why is this an issue? If I remove part of the quote, or add something, like this:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ... dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

the formatting looks odd, because I've removed one of the quote markers:

```
> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ... dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

It also breaks triple click highlighting because of the line breaks, and the only reason is it looks quoteified when you are reading the markdown (not needed nearly as much on this site).

Please can this be changed?

---

Yes, [Stop inserting hard line-wraps in blockquotes!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234299/stop-inserting-hard-line-wraps-in-blockquotes) is the same question. Let's call this a "please can this be looked at again question".

Comment: I thought this looked familiar... see [Stop inserting hard line-wraps in blockquotes!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234299/stop-inserting-hard-line-wraps-in-blockquotes)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yes... Hurumph. Wish it did solve my problem.