# Make blockquote formatting button not destroy the source layout!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, editor, blockquote

You ever had a post in front of you where the OP did mix up blockquote and code formatting? Not those easy cases where he/she wrote a `>` character before the paragraph himself, but those cases when you have several dozen lines of code or command output, often with line lengths greater than the edit window's width, and the OP used the blockquote-formatting-button!

In such cases, it does not only add the `>` character in front of *every* line, but also totally messes up every kind of indentation and reorganizes all the line breaks to fit the editor window width instead of the original structure.

You are not sure what I mean? Here is a horrible example in its original state (with blockquotes):
[Wrongly used blockquote formatted question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/605f0525-3723-4322-b439-411b5a2639b6/view-source)
And here is my attempt to fix the structure as good as I can:
[(Hopefully mostly) correct formatting](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/82986002-6008-4201-81a8-efae17772707/view-source)

**I propose to change the behavior of the `blockquote formatting button`!**

The optimal and easiest way to convert a paragraph to a blockquote would be to just write a single `>` in front of the paragraph's first line and keep all indentations and line-breaks just as they are. The output will be no different. If you have problems implementing this with checking the end of the paragraph (I don't think so, but...), it would be even an improvement if we stay with the `>` sign in front of every line selected to be formatted as blockquote and just stop reformatting the content!

Everybody who once tried to edit such a monster has to vote for this and hope for the StackExchage stuff to soon implement this. Thank you for your support and any reactions.

Comment: See also this answer to the same question on [meta.ubuntu.se]: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14189/367990

Comment: Please don't post the same question on multiple metas. The SE team read both meta.SE and all child metas so it is basically crossposting.

Comment: @terdon So should I delete the one on [meta.ubuntu.se]? But it has answers...

Comment: Well, this seems to be a dupe of [Blockquote rewrap destroys code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171197) anyway so I guess it will be closed soon.