# Don't add new lines when quoting some text

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, editor, blockquote

Current behavior: When selecting some text and clicking on the "quote" icon, `>` are added as well as new lines.

For example:

```
CRISPR gene editing is a genetic engineering technique in molecular biology by which the genomes of living organisms may be modified. It is based on a simplified version of the bacterial CRISPR-Cas9 antiviral defense system.
```

becomes

[image]

```
> CRISPR gene editing is a genetic engineering technique in molecular
> biology by which the genomes of living organisms may be modified. It
> is based on a simplified version of the bacterial CRISPR-Cas9
> antiviral defense system.
```

Notice how there are line break characters that are actually *inserted into the quote*, rather than just being a side effect of word wrapping.

Instead, I'd prefer to have:

[image]

```
> CRISPR gene editing is a genetic engineering technique in molecular biology by which the genomes of living organisms may be modified. It is based on a simplified version of the bacterial CRISPR-Cas9 antiviral defense system.
```

Notice that it only prepended a single angle bracket, with no line breaks inserted. In the post editor, the words will automatically be wrapped, as shown in the image; the text snippet below it is to demonstrate the actual text content.

Would it be possible not to add new lines when using the "quote" button?

Comment: I agree. This often ends up being an issue with quotes that are frequently edited (e.g. "notes"): the edits often result in very uneven line breaks that are harder to digest. Much easier to just let the editor display wrapped lines rather than manually wrap with automatic line breaks.

Comment: If you only want a single `>`, why not just type one? It makes sense to me that the buttons do things that *aren't* trivial.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I sometimes want to quote several paragraphs

Comment: So type several `>`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so basically you're against the quote button?

Comment: That isn't at all what I've written, it's still useful *if you want the current behaviour*, hard wrapping the lines. If you don't, it's easy to do yourself. You don't really offer a reason *why* anything should be change, aside from *"I'd prefer"*; have you seen a rendering problem caused by the current behaviour, for example? The two alternatives you've shown are indistinguishable in the rendered output.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what's the point of hard wrapping?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171312/248731 - but that's not particularly relevant, I'm not advocating for hard wrapping, *you're advocating for change*. Why isn't this [tag:feature-request]?

Comment: @jonrsharpe how does hard wrapping improve readability on quoted text? I'm advocating for the quote button to do only its job and not something else.

Comment: Well not really *advocating*, though, you're just saying you'd prefer something different. Not to put too fine a point on it: so what? It's going to involve someone doing some work, making and testing and deploying a change, which means their other work gets deferred. So *make a case*, quote precedent (have you read e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171197/248731, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234299/248731 - research is expected on metas too), show how that would be *better* not just different. Explain why anyone else should care what you'd prefer.

Comment: The way it's always worked is that you type (or copy paste) a few paragraphs, put a double quote on each end, select the text, and click on the double quote button to place a **single** > symbol at the start of each paragraph; word wrapping being determined by: your browser, font size, screen width, wind direction, etc. --- Hard breaks are [**added** by putting **2 spaces** at the EOL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/should-the-markdown-renderer-treat-a-single-line-break-as-br). - Franck's tagged as Support, I see it as a Bug, yet another believes it's a FR. --- G

Comment: FWIW, if we were starting with a blank sheet of paper, I'd be with you - do the simple thing, unless someone can argue convincingly that we *should* do the extra work of adding the line breaks. But we're not starting with a blank sheet of paper, so you need to make a case for the change.

Comment: @Rob *"way it's always worked"* where? I don't recall this having been different on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, regarding:  "way it's always worked" where? I don't recall ... --- I'm not saying whether my time machine is working; not sure how I'm supposed to show "where" when it no longer works the way it did. --- If you [compare the four possible outcomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BDnJ.jpg) you can see that the fourth case (lower right) looks normal; would not people have complained earlier if it were otherwise.    ---    [Image Descriptions: UL: Org, UR: > every line, LL: Double space, LR: One > per paragraph].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Marking this specific request as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) because we are not going to be making any more changes to the current editor.

The good news is that this behavior is functioning as you are looking for in the new Stacks Editor, which is currently live on Stack Overflow for Teams, and which we have plans for eventual release on the public SE network. It is something that we are working on (and will be posting more on MSE soon about editor details, and plans for testing and release).

---

> wont fix now — deferred
> fixed in the new editor
> more details coming

Comment: Wouldn't [tag:status-deferred] be a more accurate tag, since the feature (regardless of which editor it's in) is going to be implemented at some indeterminate time?

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog good point, corrected

Comment: Will the new Stacks editor also be used in tag wikis, profile descriptions and election nominations? That might partially fix [this image uploader bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353729/289905) and a few related bugs, e.g. the link button having `http://` instead of `https://` as a placeholder.

Comment: +1 for the ironically missing newline in the quoted haiku

Comment: @Franck, while the new editor doesn't show live previews the same as the current editor you can [see from this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACy5d.jpg) that the use of the ***"*** (quote button) causes one **>** before and after the paragraph (on the newline); that is shown in the upper image. The result of that is shown in the lower image. Presumably that's very close to what you wanted, with an equal resulting output.

Comment: @ollie ask me again when the editor is live for everyone, and not just in opt in alpha testing on two sites