# How can I automatically edit all my answers and questions so that no quotes are broken down?

Tags: support, answers, markdown, code-formatting, blockquote

The [CommonMark migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/178179) messed up the formatting of many of my posts. Specifically, one common issue is that my quotes are now broken down, e.g.:

[image]

instead of

[image]

Screenshots taken from https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/234029/12359.

I do not intend to have such broken down quotes in any of my posts. How can I automatically edit all my answers and questions so that no quotes are broken down? Adding `>` manually is tedious.

Note that [I don't want to add new lines when quoting some text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356348/178179).

Comment: If quotes were the *only* mismatch between the previous rendering and the CommonMark rendering, the post would have been automatically edited by Community to fix the problem. If your post contains a badly-formatted quote and it wasn't automatically edited, it means that there was something else in the post that was rendering differently, which wasn't programmed for in the automated script. That other thing won't render correctly if you only fix the quotes.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog thank you, how can I know what is that other thing?

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog "If quotes were the only mismatch between the previous rendering and the CommonMark rendering, the post would have been automatically edited by Community to fix the problem." That is not true. I have visited posts of mine where the quote no longer showed up in the formatted text. (Seems it might sometimes involve a line "> " followed by text on the next line.)

Comment: As [I previously said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356348/dont-add-new-lines-when-quoting-some-text#comment1190737_356348), just [do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Eg8W.jpg). Have a bot search for the existing text and replace it with that suggestion. I think SEDE can also search for raw text, looking for a quoted line followed by a new line, then another quote; offering a list to manually add three characters to each location, if that's easier than modifying an existing bot.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/1412391?UserId=12359) to find posts where subsequent blockquotes are present as generated by the Markdown parser.

```sql
select id [Post Link]
from posts
where 
body like concat(
  '%</p>', char(10), 
  '</blockquote>', char(10), 
  '<blockquote>',  char(10),
  '<p>%')
and owneruserid = ( case when ##userid:int?12359## = 0 
                    then owneruserid 
                    else ##userid:int?12359##
                    end)
```

On Cross Validated that is your only post. Overall there are [118 of such posts on Cross Validated](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/1412396)