# Quote button shouldn't reformat code in triple-backticks

Tags: bug, code-formatting, blockquote

I've seen [Blockquote rewrap destroys code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171197/), but that question (and answer) are about the situation where a user mistakenly uses the quote button instead of the code button.

I instead want to use *both*.  For example, I might want to quote code from another source (often from the question).  If I have some code explicitly enclosed in triple-backticks:

````
```c
int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```
````

then selecting that and pressing the quote button gives me:

````
> ```c int main(void) {
>     printf("Hello world!\n"); } ```
````

I cannot imagine that this is deliberate.  I claim that text in triple-backticks should be left alone, and each line instead should just be prefixed with `>` .

Update:

Trying [the Stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor) in Markdown mode, I seem to get an even worse monstrosity:

`````
 > ```c> c> int main(void) { > {> printf("Hello world!\n");)> ;> }
 > ````>
`````

(Never mind, that is an unrelated bug.)

Comment: Unable to repro here on MSE, using the new Alpha version of the Stacks editor.

Comment: @Luuklag Huh.  I just enabled the Stacks editor and tried it, and in Markdown mode, it does still seem to be a problem for me (and actually seems *worse*; see my edited question).

Comment: The stacks editor only works when composing answers.

Comment: @Luuklag Yes, I know.  I drafted an answer to try it, and I got a different result than with the usual editor.

Comment: @jamesdlin So is this talking about the old editor, or the new one, or both?

Comment: @zcoop98 The old editor.

Answer (score 1):

For me this works fine here on Meta Stack Exchange. I copied the code from your quoted block in your question. Posted it here, selected everything, and hit the blockquote button, resulting in this when in markdown mode:

> ```c
> int main(void) {
> printf("Hello world!\n");
> }
> ```

And this when done in rich text mode:

> ```c
> int main(void) {
>     printf("Hello world!\n");
> }
> ```

Comment: Okay, I am able to reproduce your behavior if I select the code lines with Shift+arrow keys and press the quote button.  Oddly, if I press Ctrl+A to select everything and press the quote button, it prefixes lines with `> ` *and* rewraps all of the lines (and inexplicably sometimes inserts other characters).

Comment: I just selected with my mouse. The Ctrl + A part is a known bug I think. There must be an answer in the announcement post on the alpha editor that adresses that.

Comment: Ah, so it is.  Anyway, it doesn't quite leave the triple-backticked text alone in Markdown mode, where it discards indentation. =/

Comment: @jamesdlin Looks like [I mentioned this behavior in the bug thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/366295#366295) last week. It's not limited to code blocks, `Ctrl+A` and then quote blocking has weird results no matter what the content is.